# SwiftUI: How can I get the width of a device?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to add padding to the left and right of a `Text()` view only. Ideally I would like to set it's width equal to the width of the device minus a constant I define.

For example:

```
Text("My text view here")
   .frame(width: device.width - 16)
```

What is the correct way to do this in SwiftUI? Am I approaching this the wrong way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## SwiftUI Standard way

`GeometryReader` is the type that gives you all information about the parent `view`

So you can use `GeometryReader` like:

```
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            Text("My text view here")
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width - 16)
                .background(Color.red) // This is just to see how it looks like
        }
    }
```

## UIKit Aggressive way

You can get it directly from the device:

```
    var body: some View {
        Text("My text view here")
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 16)
            .background(Color.red) // This is just to see how it looks like
    }
```

<sub>**Note that** device width is physical and **not** updating on rotation. Also I haven't experimented with it to see myself, but I have read the **UIScreen** runs into problems on **SplitView**.</sub>

Comment: Interesting - So you need to wrap the view in a `GeometryReader` in order to even get the width? This looks fairly inefficient.

Comment: It would be better to be something like an environment variable I think but this is how it works.

Comment: I added another way @StevenSchafer. Check that out.

Comment: your second answer is what I would expect to be able to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

An alternate way to achieve the same thing is `.padding(.horizontal, 16)`

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the frame to the full width of the screen (maxWidth: .infinity) and then adding horizontal padding.

```
Text("My text view here")
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .padding(.horizontal, 16)
```